# Pandas: Finding overlapping regions based on start- and stop coordinates

Tags: python, pandas

I want to identify rows with start- and stop positions that overlap with the start- and stop position of other rows. There are a few restrictions that apply:

1. The rows I want to check are a subset of the entire data set
2. The rows in the subset should be compared to the entire data set
3. <s>The rows should not be compared with themselves</s>

Below is a minimal representation of the data set:

```
   id type  start  stop
0   1   AP      0    10
1   2   AP      3     7
2   3   ES      5    15
3   4   ES     12    18
```

Here's an image that describes the problem better. Each box represent an event/row, and the number represents their `ID`:
[image: Overlapping exons]

And here's my desired output:

```
   id type  start  stop  number_of_overlapping_exons
0   1   AP      0    10                            2
1   2   AP      3     7                            2
```

I want to find the rows with `type` equal to AP that have other rows (of any type) that overlap their position. In the image above, the blue boxes represent AP events. There are two events/rows overlapping blue box 1 (boxes 2 and 3), so the `number_of_overlapping_exons` for `ID` 1 should be 2. Blue box 2 also has two overlapping events (boxes 1 and 3). Here's what I've got so far:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample input
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "type": ["AP", "AP", "ES", "ES"],
    "start": [0, 3, 5, 12],
    "stop": [10, 7, 15, 18]
})

# Extract only AP events
ap = df.loc[df.type == "AP"]

# Find events that overlap start positions in "ap"
# by identifying "start" or "stop" positions in "df"
# that are greater or equal to "start" positions in "ap".
overlapping_start_positions = df.loc[(df.start >= ap.start) | (df.stop >= ap.start)]
# Find events that overlap stop positions in "ap"
# by identifying "start" or "stop" positions in "df"
# that are smaller or equal to "stop" positions in "ap".
overlapping_stop_positions = df.loc[(df.start <= ap.stop) | (df.stop <= ap.stop)]
```

I'm getting a `ValueError` when doing `overlapping_start_positions` saying

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

**EDIT:**

Come to think of it, condition 3:

3. The rows should not be compared with themselves

is not really required. All events will overlap with themselves, so I can just subtract 1 from `number_of_overlapping_exons`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there is a clever way to do this in one pass, but a brute force solution is to just loop over the rows in the dataframe.

For example:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample input
df = pd.DataFrame({
    "id": [1, 2, 3, 4],
    "type": ["AP", "AP", "ES", "ES"],
    "start": [0, 3, 5, 12],
    "stop": [10, 7, 15, 18]
})
df['count'] = 0

for row in df.itertuples():
    mask = (row.start <= df.stop) & (row.stop >= df.start)
    df.loc[row.Index, 'count'] = sum(mask) - 1
```

And we get

```
   id  start  stop type  count
0   1      0    10   AP      2
1   2      3     7   AP      2
2   3      5    15   ES      3
3   4     12    18   ES      1
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was afraid I'd have to resort to loops. Currently testing your solution on approx. 2 million rows. Do you happen to have any idea of the complexity of this?

Comment: Not really. I would guess n^2: n for accessing each row, and O(n) comparisons for each row.

Comment: 2M^2, yikes! But I just realized I have some major redundancy and can reduce the data down to a 56th. Thanks again!